# Metric functions induce clusters with infinite many points in each cluster

Tags: metric-spaces, symmetric-groups, geometric-topology, mahalanobis-distance

Consider the family of metric function $d: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow [0, 1] $ with the following properties:

1. Coincidence: $d(x, y) = 0  \Longleftrightarrow x = y, \forall x, y$
2. Symmetry: $d(x, y) = d(y, x), \forall x, y$
3. Triangle inequality: $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z) , \forall x, y, z$

For a fixed set of vectors $\left\{ \textbf{v}_1, ..., \textbf{v}_n \right\}$ where $\mathbf{v}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and no two vectors are the same ($\forall i, j: \mathbf{v}_i \neq \mathbf{v}_j$), prove that there are infinite many points in $\mathbf{v}_i$'s neighborhood.
That is, there are infinite points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that satisfy the following, for a fixed $i$:
$$
d(\textbf{x}, \textbf{v}_i) < d(\textbf{x}, \textbf{v}_j), \forall i \neq j 
$$

If this is not true, what additional properties does $d(., .)$ metric need to have for this to be true?

---

For example, if $d$ is a dot product, this is definitely true
since, for a fixed $i$, there are infinite $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ that satisfy the following:
$$
\textbf{x}.\textbf{v}_i < \textbf{x}.\textbf{v}_j, \forall i \neq j 
$$

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the set $\mathcal{D}$ of *all* metrics?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma dropped it.

Comment: Then it’s false without assumptions on $d$.

Comment: The three mentioned properties are for $d$, right?

Comment: Yes but there are many such functions on $\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: Right, I also mention in the post that, "If this is not true, what additional properties does (.,.) metric need to have for this to be true?"

Comment: Lowercase $d$ is being used for the symmetric function $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ as well as for the dimension $\mathbb R^d$.  It's a minor nitpick, but surely we could instead ask the dimension to be $n$, say $\mathbb R^n$?